# Event binding on dynamic HTML, using fetch and within forEach

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, fetch, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener on the HTML element show belown, generated dynamically within a forEach loop. I'm getting the proper response from the JSON Placeholder API initially, however, none of my attempts to bind an event on any of the HTML elements I generate after the initial response seem to produce result when I try out the event.

I'm either getting no 'Clicked' at all or ... `addEventListener` is not a function, depending on where I put the `addEventListener` code.

Is there any way to make this possible in a clean and reusable way?
Also, is this the preferred way of generating dynamic HTML through vanilla JS? Or should I generate it manually, by using `document.createElement()` and `appendChild()` for example?

Ultimately, I am meaning to pass the ID of the clicked target to the `getPosts` function fetch URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => createResult(data));

function createResult(data) {
  const container = document.getElementById('result');

  data.forEach((user) => {
    const { id, name, email, address: { city, street } } = user;

    let result =
      `<div class="user" data-uid=${id}>
          <h5 id="user-${id}"> User ID: ${id} </h5>
            <ul class="w3-ul">
              <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
              <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
              <li> User Address : ${city}, ${street} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;

    container.innerHTML += result;
    
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (e.target &&
        e.target.classList.contains("user")) {
        console.log('Clicked');
      }
    });
  });
}

function getPosts(e) {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${user.id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

```html
<div id=result></div>
```

Comment: Assuming you have a `result` element, it looks to work, though you should only attach the listener once, not every time

Comment: Why do you add a new `click` handler to `document.body` _for every element in `data`_? Add the `click` handler to `#result`

Comment: @Andreas It's something I tried after coming across Event Delegation online. I honestly don't know of that's the way to go though. Normally I'd just add an event listener on the element itself, but that does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The click event you mean? I'm getting the initial response back succesfully, coming from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. The click event does not fire at all.

Comment: Because there's only an "element" after the `.innerHTML += ...` part (which kills all already attached event handlers!). You would then have to attach the event to the last child of `#result`. Stick with event delegation but only add one handler to `#result` and use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: @Andreas do you mean like this? container.insertAdjacentHTML += result;

    result.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (e.target &&
        e.target.classList.contains("user")) {
        console.log('Clicked');
      }
    });

Comment: No. Please find a documentation (e.g. MDN) for `.insertAdjacentHTML()` and read how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach. The first problem is that you add the `click` handler to `document.body` for every element in `data`.

If you call `createResult()` only once then move the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) call before or after the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
container.addEventListener("click", ...);
data.forEach(...);
```

If you call `createResult()` multiple times then move the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) out of it and maybe call it on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('result').addEventListener("click", ...);
});
```

The second problem is `e.target`. `e.target` is the element that triggered the `click` event. And this most likely wont be `div.result` but an element in `div.result`. You have to traverse up the DOM until you find `div.result`. A possible way can be to use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) or a loop and [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

```js
fakeFetch().then(createResult);

function createResult(data) {
  const container = document.getElementById('result');

  container.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const user = e.target.closest(".user");
    
    if (user) {
      getPosts(user.dataset.uid);
    }
  });

  data.forEach((user) => {
    const { id, name, email, address: { city, street } } = user;

    let result =
      `<div class="user" data-uid="${id}">
          <h5 id="user-${id}"> User ID: ${id} </h5>
            <ul class="w3-ul">
              <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
              <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
              <li> User Address : ${city}, ${street} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;

    container.innerHTML += result;
  });
}

function getPosts(userId) {
  console.log(userId);
}

function fakeFetch() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const user = [
      { id: 1, name: "a", mail: "a@a.a", address: { city: "a", street: "a" } },
      { id: 2, name: "b", mail: "b@b.b", address: { city: "b", street: "b" } }
    ];
    
    setTimeout(resolve(user), 1000);
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

And as a second note:
Don't use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). This will overwrite the content of the element and therefor remove any event handlers. Use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

```js
container.innerHTML += result
```

would then be

```js
container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result);
```

Comment: I'll read up on Element.insertAdjacentHTML() like you said. This approach makes a lot sense. Could you tell me, whether I would be better off generating HTML with createElement and such instead of the way I'm doing now?  Asking for future practice purposes, because I have not seen many people creating HTML like this, it might make things unnessecary complex.

Comment: If you build the DOM purely (or on a larger scale) with JavaScript you definitely want to have a look at a library for this (react/vue/...). The DOM methods (`.createElement()`, `.appendChild()`, ...) will almost guarantee you that you don't do anything bad to or with the DOM. If you're absolutely sure that a string only contains valid HTML then use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of the old `.innerHTML`

Comment: And if you use event delegation always add the event handler to the closest possible parent node. If you're only interested in clicks on `#result` then use `#result`. Adding it to, e.g. `body`, will cause your event handler to be executed for every click on the page and you will have to add additional checks for when the click has happened inside of `#result`

Comment: I'll definitely look into those libraries. I've been meaning to build a calendar webapp, allowing users to register, view their agenda for the day/week/month, change their agenda etc. This makes for a lot of dynamic HTML, so using React or Vue will probably be beneficial like you mentioned. Appreciate all the good info!

Answer (score 2):

You should make each result an element and add event listener to that element only

```
let element = document.createElement('div')
element.innerHTML = result
element = element.firstChild

element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  console.log('Clicked', element.getAttribute('data-uid'));
});

container.appendChild(element);
```

**Runnable example**

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => createResult(data));

function createResult(data) {
  const container = document.getElementById('result');

  data.forEach((user) => {
    const { id, name, email, address: { city, street } } = user;

    let result =
      `<div class="user" data-uid=${id}>
          <h5 id="user-${id}"> User ID: ${id} </h5>
            <ul class="w3-ul">
              <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
              <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
              <li> User Address : ${city}, ${street} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;

    let element = document.createElement('div')
    element.innerHTML = result
    element = element.firstChild
    
    element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      console.log('Clicked', element.getAttribute('data-uid'));
    });
    
    container.appendChild(element);
  });
}

function getPosts(e) {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${user.id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

```html
<div id=result></div>
```

Comment: Do you know if, in a professional setting, it is more common to generate HTML like I have in my post (like a string) or by generating through createElement and the likes? I'm getting into experimenting with fetch, so I would like to know which is the preferred way to get me onto the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Should work if

1. You attach the eventListener ONCE to document.body
2. You add a third param to the addEventListener call, specifying to use CAPTURE not BUBBLING.

```js
function createResult(data) {
  const container = document.getElementById('result');

  data.forEach((user) => {
    const { id, name, email, address: { city, street } } = user;

    let result =
      `<div class="user" data-uid=${id}>
          <h5 id="user-${id}"> User ID: ${id} </h5>
            <ul class="w3-ul">
              <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
              <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
              <li> User Address : ${city}, ${street} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;

    container.innerHTML += result;
  });
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target &&
    e.target.classList.contains("user")) {
    console.log('Clicked element ' + e.target.data.uid);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Ah yes, that made the difference! How would you go about passing the clicked element's ID to the fetch param in the getPosts function?

Comment: `e.target.data.uid`

Comment: It's `.dataset` not `.data`